# use of dummy variables in regression equation

Tags: regression, categorical-data, categorical-encoding

I have data where the regressor of interest is 7-point Likert scale responses to a questionnaire regarding experiences.  These people are answering questions regarding a group with which they have interacted . Response levels 6 & 7 correspond to "strongly agreeing" with statements in the questionnaire.

I want to find the relationship between these attitudinal variables and an response variable (overall experience score) to see what "drives" the overall experience score.  It would be most helpful to view this relationship as an X change in the percent of individuals indicating a 6 or 7 on each attitudinal factor contributes to Y change in overall experience score.  Then I want to take that regression equation and plug in a group's overall score across participants into the equation and play around with the percentage to get a projected experience score outcome.  so the *group* becomes the unit of analysis when computing the equation.

Here is my question: how would I recode the variables to look at this relationship?  If I code each of the attitudinal statements as 0 (1-5) and 1 (6-7 original code) and then throw those in the regression equation my coefficients are just intercept dummy variables and not able to look at the impact of changes in the % that rate them high (a six or a seven), correct?

Comment: You can use the Likert scales variables in the regression. The question is would they make a sense in your particular case? Did you look at SEM (structural equation modeling)?

Comment: Are you calculating a total score from the same experience based questions that you are using to relate to the total score? Or did you separately ask experience based questions as well as a total score, e.g. "my overall impression of the group was..."?

Is your goal to identify which groups performed best overall, or which groups have different relationships between experience based outcomes and total score? What are the sample sizes (participants and groups and avg participants per group)

Comment: the overall score is derived from an entirely different question that the attitudinal statements on the 7 point scale.

Comment: The research question i'm trying to get at is this: "How does a change in the percentage of respondents that rated a group highly on the items (so the % that rated them a 6 or 7 on the scale) impact the overall assessment of the group. The overall assessment is not derived from the individual items.